# Modal not being called on bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have this following code:

```
<div class="btn slick-slide slick-active" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#photo-carousel-modal" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 234px;">
    <img class="img-holder img-thumbnail" src="image/path.jpg">
</div>
```

That was supposed to call for this modal here:

```
 <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="photo-carousel-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            {{-- Modal's content --}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It simply not triggers anything! Am I doing some stupidity and not realizing it?

**P.S.:** YES! The Bootstrap does work properly. I'm using it in other parts of the code and it works like a charm!

Comment: Its working fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/kpktr7hy/** so it **is** something else that breaks it up :)

Comment: Check if you have any other div with the same `id`, that happened to me once ;)

Comment: @TomSarduy The ID is UNIQUE. I already tried it.

Comment: @davidkonrad It's interesting that is working outside the rest of my code. The "button" that is calling the modal is a photo, being placed on a carousel animated by [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `bootstrap.js` file is called **AFTER** your jQuery file like this:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery-file.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

(Also, remove any other bootstrap js file like bootstrap-modal.js, etc as bootstrap.js has everything in it already)

If the above is already done and it still is not showing, please post the codes from your `<head....</head` and the footer of your webpage on your question.

**P.S.** Check your browser console for errors so you can get a better idea on what is going on.

Comment: hmm. That is weird. IF possible, can you give me a link to the webpage Dennis?

Comment: It's on my localhost yet.

Comment: oh I see. Can you post the whole html in jsfiddle (without the css) please.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact that I use Laravel 5 "built-in" Bootstrap. Somehow they are messing up, and BStrap can't reach for jQuery due to placement order.

Comment: That does sound like it could cause issues with the placement order yes. How is laravel adding the bootstrap?

Comment: Found it, I'll make a answer. It was the other guy that works here who places jQuery 3 (three!) times.

Answer (score 0):

I found out later that my code had 3 call for jQuery library. one of them was after the bootstrap call. That's where I messed up!

(As a matter of fact, it was the other guy who works here.)

So, kids: DO NOT PLACE YOUR JQUERY CALL AFTER THE BOOTSTRAP CALL! It will make you go nuts!