# Bootstrap modal call will not run, possible constructor issue

Tags: jquery, constructor, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, class-constructors

I'm building a portfolio site and I want to use Bootstrap modals, but I can't get the modals to pop open. There seems to be something wrong with the JQuery, am I calling this correctly?

I found this question [Modal not being called on bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660360/modal-not-being-called-on-bootstrap-3), and it's the closest to the problem I've had. But I tried rearranging my  links to no avail. I've also tried downloading and linking the .js files natively in case there was an error in the .js files I was linking to, but it didn't resolve my problem.

Here's the code to call the modal within my body segment:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Click to open Modal
    </button>
```

And here is how I've linked to the .js files in the header:

```
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">


    <script src="jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>

    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">

</head>
```

This should cause a modal window to pop up, but for some reason nothing is happening.

Upon inspecting the code in Chrome it looks like the problem is with the constructor "_dataApiClickHandler" but since I don't write Java I'm not sure how to resolve this. Any help or links to similar issues would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: amend your question to show your modal. I have a pretty good idea of your issue but need to see that first.

Comment: This is one of those really humbling moments - I didn't build any modal content, I literally just built a button assuming it would conjure a modal window. I see now why nothing opened - thanks for you help!

Comment: Toink..........